# How can you hook a script that will run after simply saving a file?

Tags: bash, hook, file-watcher

So, I wrote a fast script that you run with ". .script [name]".  It's stupid simple, but I love it.  Took me like an hour or so and a good dose of Stack Overflow. :P

I use Codekit on an iMac at work.  I set it up as a hook, not understanding the coolness of those.  So, I came home and tried it with Prepros.  My conclusion:  "Not sure.  Don't think so."

How do I get Windows, OS X and Ubuntu/CentOS to watch a file in a specified project directory, and run the script I tell it to when I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fswatch might be what you want. It support both linux, windows and MacOS.

http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/

Comment: Figured I'd come back and let you know that I feel this is a better answer since it's a cross-platform solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without encoding support for each system's respective filesystem event notifier (linux has inotifytools, and I don't know what the rest do), you can poll for timestamp changes and run your hook if one takes place:

```
tm=$(stat -c%Y file) #get the m(odification)time of file
while : ; do 
   last_tm=$tm
   tm=$(stat -c%Y file) 
   [ "$last_tm" = "$tm" ] || echo "file changed"
   sleep 0.2 #poll interval
done
```